# react native splash image auto height

Tags: android, react-native, splash-screen

I try to make a splash screen in react-native.
I installed "react-native-splash-screen" package to my project. I created a splash screen.

I want to do this.

- My image's width fill the screen and height should protect image ratio.

So I try this.

**layout / launch_screen.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="@drawable/background_splash"
      android:orientation="vertical">
    </LinearLayout>
```

**drawable/ background_splash.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:drawable="@color/splashscreen_bg"/>

    <item
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:drawable="@drawable/splashtest"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:gravity="center" />

</layer-list>
```

[image]

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

I correct .xml files like this and problem solved.

**background_splash.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@color/splashscreen_bg"/>    
</layer-list>
```

**launch_screen.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_splash"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/splashtest"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```